# Upload Image in flutter via restApi (Not working in iOS) working on Android

Tags: rest, http, flutter, multipart, flutter-dependencies

Hi All not able to upload image on server working fine in android but not in iOS 
status code = 200 in android 
status code = 403 in iOS

```
static Upload(File image) async {
    String apiUrl = host + '/api/v1/profile/mobile/picture/new';
    var storage = SecureStorage();
    var authToken = await storage.getToken();
    Map<String, String> headers = {"Authorization": authToken};
    var postUri = Uri.parse(apiUrl);
    http.MultipartRequest request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", postUri);
    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    request.files.add(
      await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', image.path),
    );
    request.send().then((response) {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) print("Uploaded!");
    });
  }
```

Comment: Please modify the question, what is working and what's not clear.

Comment: done modifyed question

Comment: show your back-end code, how you're handling the data

Comment: backend using apigateway then send into s3 image bucket

Comment: Do you use real devices for both Android and iOS or virtual one?

Comment: i tested in both real and virtual

Comment: @AnandAtul any update on this? I am having the same issue

Comment: @Anasiqbal yes now its working for me

Comment: What yuou did to solve?